# Alphabetical topological sorting in ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, topological-sort, alphabetical-sort

Let's say I have this tree of dependencies:

[image: view dependencies graph]

```
digraph G {
    view1_1 -> view1
    view1_2 -> view1
    a_view1_1_1 -> view1_1
    c_view1_and_1_1 -> view1_1
    c_view1_and_1_1 -> view1
    z_view1_1_2 -> view1_1
}
```

How can I get this as the resulting order:

```
view1
view1_1
a_view1_1_1
c_view1_and_1_1
view1_2
z_view1_1_2
```

For some context, it's to make a reproducible file output on an open-source project: https://github.com/thoughtbot/scenic/pull/191

I started implementing a mix of tsort and raw alphabetical sorting, e.g.:

Comment: You need to specify the rules that establish the order. It's not obvious, for example, why do `c_view1_and_1_1` and `view1_2` precede `z_view1_1_2`. I assume it has something to do with the alphabetic ordering.  I suggest you make `digraph` a hash, so readers will have a common input (e.g., `digraph = {  :view1_1 => :view1, ... }`. Please clarify by editing.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I included a hash in my proposed answer

Answer (score 1):

I realized the output tsort gave me is actually correct even if not the same as what my intuition was:

```
require 'tsort'

tree = {
  "view1" => [],
  "view1_1" => ["view1"],
  "view1_2" => ["view1"],
  "a_view1_1_1" => ["view1_1"],
  "c_view1_and_1_1" => ["view1_1", "view1"],
  "z_view1_1_2" => ["view1_1"],
}

class Hash
  include TSort

  def tsort_each_node(&block)
    keys.sort.each(&block)
  end

  def tsort_each_child(node, &block)
    fetch(node).each { |n| yield(n) }
  end
end

tree = Hash[*tree.to_a.shuffle.flatten(1)]

puts tree.tsort

# BONUS: p tree.strongly_connected_components
```

Which gives:

```
view1
view1_1
a_view1_1_1
c_view1_and_1_1
view1_2
z_view1_1_2
```